# Event natively fired on prompt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, prompt

Is there an event fired when the [prompt](http://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_rl_prompt_preservecursor) function is run ? I would like to register to that event, to do something when there is a prompt in my code.

Unfortunately, I didn't find anything on the doc :/

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried creating your custom [`Events`](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_event_newlistener)? BTW There isn't seem any event for `prompt`